# Некорректно происходит вставка контента Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где искать настройки для корректной вставки скопированного контента?
Вставляю, как на картинке, текст из Авокода и строка уезжает в самое начало. Не работает cmd+shift+v как в Sublime Text 3. И происходит такая вставка некорректная во всех типах файла. Не нашел в настройках такого функционала..

Comment: В vs code удобное ручное форматирование, `ctrl (или cmd) + k (отпускаем k) + f`. Работает как на весь документ так и на кусок выделенного кода.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтоб вставляемый текст не "прыгал" при вставках через ctrl+v/вставить необходимо отключить настройку

> **editor.formatOnPaste**

Фрагмент из коммента к настройке VSCode

```
// Определяет, будет ли редактор автоматически форматировать
// вставленное содержимое. Модуль форматирования должен быть доступен
// и иметь возможность форматировать диапазон в документе.

"editor.formatOnPaste": false
```